# How to activate 'Zoom to rectangle' by command line in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, zooming

In pyplot, I am usually plotting large amounts of data and hence, always using ZOOM (by pressing the 'Zoom to rectangle' button, which got kind of bothering always doing that). Is there a way to activate the zoom function by command line in python? Have searched for it a lot, but no luck. I wish something like that would be possible:

```
plt.pyplot(X,Y) # plot some data
plt.zoom_activate() # !! activate the 'Zoom to rectangle' - that's what Im looking for
plt.show() # show the pyplot
```

Comment: Set the axis range with `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`.

Comment: Im aware of these commands, but that means I should re-run the code for every plt.xlim,plt.ylim change, which would be even more time consuming. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you're looking for is

```
fig.canvas.toolbar.zoom()
```

if `fig` is a matplotlib figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the same problem as me, my solution was to use

```
plt.pause(.1)
```

which "updates and displays current figure before pause".